# Two blank lines after function

Tags: python, anaconda, pep8

The PEP 8 style guide says to surround top level functions with [two blank lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines). I have Sublime Text configured with Anaconda, so it highlights the need to put two blank lines after each function in Flask. But I noticed on GitHub that nobody is following this style guideline. Should I stop following it?

How do I tell Anaconda to stop identifying the lack of two blank lines as errors?

I found that I can disable the error in Sublime Text by editing Anaconda.sublime-settings and adding "E302":

```
 "pep8_ignore":
    [
        "E309",
        "E302"
    ],
```

Comment: How many Github projects did you really look at? [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/templating.py) for example does seem to follow that

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe I looked at some smaller projects that were not following the guidelines. I'll just stick to using two blank lines.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The PEP 8 style guidance to add two blank lines after classes and functions is followed by major open source projects. I will keep doing it!